# echo info from a multidimensional array in another

Tags: php, arrays

How do i echo/print_r url arry `code=>'LV_ARTICLES_ARTICLECODE'` from the folowing code in another php file that is in the same dir?

```
function BuildSearchIndex($showHomePage = False,$functionLanguage) 
{
   $index_arr = array
   (
     array
     (
     'directory'=>'data/articles',//bestands locatie is data/articles/ "alles"
     'files_ext'=>array('xml'),//bestands extentie is "xml"
     'tags'=>array //alle tags zijn tussen de <> tekens
            (
            'LV_ARTICLES_DESCRIPTION' //artiekel omschrijvings tag

            /*,'LV_ARTICLES_DESCRIPTIONANDMEASURE',
            'LV_ARTICLES_SPECIFICATION'*/,

            'LV_ARTICLES_ARTICLECODE' //artiekel code / ID tag

            /*,'LV_ARTICLES_ARTICLECODE2',
            'LV_ARTICLES_SHORTMEMO',
            'LV_ARTICLES_LONGMEMO',
            'LV_ARTICLES_ARTICLECODE2'*/
            ),

     'url'=>array
            (
            'action'=>'article',

            /*'group_id'=>'content "/<LV_ARTICLES_GROUP>.*<LV_ARTICLES_ITEM>(.+)<\/LV_ARTICLES_ITEM>.*<\/LV_ARTICLES_GROUP>/isU"',*/

            'aid'=>'filename "/article_(\d+).xml/i"'
            ),

           'name'=>'LV_ARTICLES_DESCRIPTIONANDMEASURE',
           'code'=>'LV_ARTICLES_ARTICLECODE',
           'languages'=>array(),
           'additional'=>array
                (
                'price'=>'content "/<LV_ARTICLES_PRICE_EXVAT>(.+)<\/LV_ARTICLES_PRICE_EXVAT>/iU"',
                'vat'=>'content "/<LV_ARTICLES_VAT>(.+)<\/LV_ARTICLES_VAT>/iU"',
                'manufacturer'=>'content "/<LV_ARTICLES_MANUFACTURER>(.+)<\/LV_ARTICLES_MANUFACTURER>/iU"',
                'categories'=>'content "/<LV_ARTICLES_GROUP>(.+)<\/LV_ARTICLES_GROUP>/isU"'
                )

     ),

     array
     (
     'directory'=>'data/extrapages',
     'files_ext'=>array('xml'),
     'tags'=>array('LV_TITLE','LV_BODY'),
     'url'=>array(
     'action'=>'extra',
     'extra'=>'filename "/(.+).xml/i"'),
     'name'=>'LV_TITLE',
     'languages'=>array()
     )
   );
   $clear_arr = array
   (
     0=>array('dir'=>'./data/articles',
              'languages'=>array()),
     1=>array('dir'=>'./data/extrapages',
              'languages'=>array())
   );

   $lang=$functionLanguage->getLanguageList();
   foreach ($lang as $v) 
   {
     $index_arr[0]['languages'][$v['code']]='LV_ARTICLES_LANG_'.strtoupper($v['code']);
     $index_arr[1]['languages'][$v['code']]='LV_'.strtoupper($v['code']);
     $clear_arr[0]['languages'][$v['code']]=$v['code'];
     $clear_arr[1]['languages'][$v['code']]=$v['code'];
   }

   try 
   {
     $q=new Search();
     $q->clear_index($clear_arr);
     $q->make_index($index_arr);
   } 
   catch (Exception $e) 
   {
     echo $e->__toString();
   }

   if ($showHomePage) {
     header('location: index.php?action=home&lang='.strtoupper($functionLanguage->getCurrentLanguage()));
   }

}
```

I dont know why i have to add more detail. I really think my question is clear enough. But any way I tried `$index_arr['']['url']['code']` first it might be wrong second its in a function. Can I even extract that info from there?

Comment: More detail is needed.  It looks like this might be part of a class.  And that array doesn't appear to be returned so that you can use it.  I don't think that function/method's purpose is to do so. judging by the name.

Comment: $index_arr[0]['url']['code']

Comment: thanks @Tommy for your help. i did it good i think.

Comment: @user3023611 then mark the answer if was good :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `$index_arr` in the BuildSearchIndex function. Then when you call this function from the other file you could do this:

```
$array = BuildSearchIndex($param1, $param2);
echo $array[0]['url']['code'];
```

The other way,if you can´t return the array on the function, would be pass the `$index_arr` by reference, doing something like this:

```
function BuildSearchIndex($showHomePage = False,$functionLanguage, &$index_arr) 
{
$index_arr = array
   (
     array
     (....
```

Then you call the function this way, and you will have access to the content you want:

```
$array = array();    
BuildSearchIndex($param1, $param2, $array);
echo $array[0]['url']['code'];
```

Comment: Where do I put the return?
Inside the $search_arr? Or berfore closing the function?

Comment: you should return $index_arr var at the end of BuildSearchIndex function (inside this function), like return $index_arr

Comment: thank you bot but now i am of duty and cant acces the files. after 2 weaks i wil be able to try those suggestions. thanks in advance.